# Aligning matrices in a nice way

Tags: align, matrices

[image]

Can the two matrices generated using the following code, be aligned more nicely? In this code, the left parenthesis of two matrices is aligned. Is it possible to make the top matrix lie around the middle of the bottom matrix?

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath,amssymb}
\usepackage{nicefrac}
\usepackage{multirow,array,booktabs}
\usepackage{mathtools}
\begin{document}
\begin{align}
\label{eq:1}
\big|\Tilde{\Phi}_{\boldsymbol{K}}\big\rangle &= e^{i \boldsymbol{K}.\boldsymbol{r}}
\begin{pmatrix}
|0,X\rangle\\0\\1\\1
\end{pmatrix}
\\
\label{eq:2}
\big|\Tilde{\Phi}_{\boldsymbol{K}}\big\rangle &= e^{i \boldsymbol{K}.\boldsymbol{r}}
\begin{pmatrix}
 \sin(\theta)|5,X\rangle\\0\\ \cos(\theta)|2,X\rangle\\0
\end{pmatrix}
\end{align}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Why doesn't your code compile?

Comment: While code snippets are useful in explanations, it is always best to compose a fully compilable [MWE](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228/4301) that illustrates the problem including the `\documentclass` and the appropriate packages so that those trying to help don't have to recreate it.

Comment: I have updated the necessary details.

Comment: I would suggest not to align these two formulas at all But if you really need to align, it is probably best to align on the equal signs.

Answer (score 7):

You can use `IEEEeqnarray` from `IEEEtrantools`. But I don't think it's an improvement over the original alignment. The key is to use four columns

1. `r` for right alignment
2. `C` for center alignment with spaces suitable for relations
3. `l` for left alignment
4. `c` for center alignment

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath,amssymb}
\usepackage{bm}% important!
\usepackage{IEEEtrantools}

\begin{document}

\begin{IEEEeqnarray}{rCrc}
\label{eq:1}
\bigl|\Tilde{\Phi}_{\bm{K}}\bigr\rangle &=& e^{i \bm{K}\bm{r}} &
\begin{pmatrix}
|0,X\rangle\\0\\1\\1
\end{pmatrix}
\\[1ex]
\label{eq:2}
\bigl|\Tilde{\Phi}_{\bm{K}}\bigr\rangle &=& e^{i \bm{K}\bm{r}} &
\begin{pmatrix}
 \sin(\theta)|5,X\rangle\\0\\ \cos(\theta)|2,X\rangle\\0
\end{pmatrix}
\end{IEEEeqnarray}

\end{document}
```

Note `\bigl` and `\bigr` instead of the undirected `\big`. Also the `bm` package offers better “bold symbols”. You can still use `\boldsymbol`, but `\bm` is much shorter.

I also removed the period that in math never stands for multiplication.

[image]

Answer (score 6):

One way is to use `\makebox` to create a box which is the `\widthof` the `\BottomMatrix` and center the matrix within that box:

[image]

#### Code:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{calc}

\newcommand{\BottomMatrix}{%
    \begin{pmatrix}
     \sin(\theta)|5,X\rangle\\0\\ \cos(\theta)|2,X\rangle\\0
    \end{pmatrix}
}%
\newcommand*{\MakeBox}[2]{%
    %% #1 = content whose width is to define the width of the box
    %% #2 = content to be `c`entered with the width of #1
    \makebox[\widthof{$#1$}][c]{$#2$}%
}


\begin{document}
\begin{align}
\label{eq:1}
\big|\Tilde{\Phi}_{\boldsymbol{K}}\big\rangle &= e^{i \boldsymbol{K}.\boldsymbol{r}}
\MakeBox{\BottomMatrix}{%
    \begin{pmatrix}
    |0,X\rangle\\0\\1\\1
    \end{pmatrix}
}
\\
\label{eq:2}
\big|\Tilde{\Phi}_{\boldsymbol{K}}\big\rangle &= e^{i \boldsymbol{K}.\boldsymbol{r}}
\BottomMatrix
\end{align}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 4):

The following solution assumes that you want the tall parentheses, and not just the contents of the `pmatrix` environment, to be aligned with each other.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{mathtools,bm}
\DeclarePairedDelimiter{\ket}{\lvert}{\rangle}

\newlength\mylen
% obtain width of widest cell in 2nd pmatrix:
\settowidth{\mylen}{$\cos(\theta)\ket{2,X}$} 
\newcommand\mybox[1]{\parbox{\mylen}{\centering$#1$}}

\begin{document}

\begin{align}
\label{eq:1}
\ket[\big]{\tilde{\Phi}_{\bm{K}}} 
  &= e^{i\bm{Kr}}
  \begin{pmatrix}
    \ket{0,X} \\ 0 \\ 1 \\ \mybox{0}
  \end{pmatrix} \\[\jot] % add a bit of vertical whitespace
\label{eq:2}
\ket[\big]{\tilde{\Phi}_{\bm{K}}} 
  &= e^{i\bm{Kr}}
  \begin{pmatrix}
    \sin(\theta)\ket{5,X} \\ 0 \\ \cos(\theta)\ket{2,X} \\ 0
  \end{pmatrix}
\end{align}
\end{document}
```

Comment: It's quite uncommon to see typesetting like `f    (x)` instead of `f(x)` or `f(  x  )`. Thus, if these equations must be aligned, it's nicest to align the symbols (parentheses), as done here. On the other hand, I just realized that `exp(iKr)` is not a function, so perhaps this argument is moot...

Comment: @MateenUlhaq - I've converted the `exp(iKr)` expressions back to typographically equivalent `e^{iKr}` expressions.